# How can I not upload sqlite db to heroku through git?

Tags: php, facebook, git, sqlite, heroku

I am creating a Facebook app am migrating it over to Heroku due to a lack of SSL security on my site where I was hosting it before. I am using an SQLite DB with PHP in my app. I am new to git and don't really know much about it. Really just the basics of how to push my local repo to heroku's servers. I have a question about not uploading a file. In the future I may need to make some changes to my app, but currently when I re-push my repo up to heroku, my database gets wiped out and refreshed with just the data I have currently stored locally in the DB. I have looked into both the ".gitignore" file and "git update-index --assume-unchanged filename.ext". But neither of these methods work. I'd really appreciate any suggestions from you guys who are experienced with git and how I could go about uploading everything but my SQLite database.

Thank you,
Bryce

Answer (score 0):

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged filename.ext
```

really should work as long as you don't explicitly re-add the file (like using `git add .`).  Use `git status` to make sure the file isn't marked as modified before you commit.

Another option would be to deploy a different database file in production; that way the changes to your dev database isn't important.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like the 'git add .' is what I am doing wrong. I had just seen that in one of the tutorials I had watched and not really thought about that being the problem. What should I use instead of 'git add .'?

Comment: I recommend a GUI git front end like Tower on the Mac or Tortoise git for windows http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/. You can use them to add files easier than the command line.